# Is Angelica Pickles really older than Susie Carmichael and Harold Frumpkin?

Tags: character, rugrats, all-grown-up

In the *Rugrats* spin-off *All Grown Up*, in S02E08 'Lucky 13', Angelica refers to Susie and Harold as pre-teens ('[You pre-teens wouldn't understand.](https://rugrats.fandom.com/wiki/Lucky_13/Transcript)'). However the fandom says their respective dates of birth are [Angelica - May 12, 1988](https://rugrats.fandom.com/wiki/Angelica_Pickles), [Susie - April 9, 1988](https://rugrats.fandom.com/wiki/Susie_Carmichael) and [Harold - September 20, 1987](https://rugrats.fandom.com/wiki/Harold_Frumpkin). What's going on?

Update: I've seen both the episode *Pre-School Daze* and the spin-off *Pre-School Daze*, and I haven't found anything that helps here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Evidence of what their actual ages are

I'm not entirely sure where the fandom site did get the information on their dates of birth. I found this IMDB link that says Angelica is the oldest: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101188/trivia?item=tr1125424. Again not entirely sure how accurate that is compared to the fandom website. No sources are listed on either site from what I can tell. But this at least indicates it is possible that Angelica is correct that perhaps she is a teen already and Susie and Harold are preteens.

#### From the standpoint that their ages are correct on the fandom website

I would say it is just in her character to say things like that. Sure she is the same age as Susie and Harold, but she still considers herself superior. More of an adult/teen than they are. She has always had a high opinion of herself compared to others so I think it fits for her to say something like that.

Comment: so the dates of birth are correct?

Comment: I'm not actually sure if they are correct dates. I haven't looked into it. I guess I was more saying that even if she was indeed their same age it still makes sense for her to say something like that. But if those dates of birth are incorrect and Angelica is older then that makes sense too.

Comment: @BCLC I updated my answer a bit for clarity.